# View Binding return null

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-viewbinding

In the Bottom sheet dialog

```
class XBottomSheet () : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: XBottomSheetBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var handlerRunner: Runnable? = null
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = XBottomSheetBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        handlerRunner = Runnable {
            binding.tvTimeOffer.text = "text"
       }
       
       handler.postDelayed(handlerRunner!!, 1)
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null

        handlerRunner?.apply {
            handler.removeCallbacks(this)
        }
    }
}
```

In some phones Firebase carashlytics logs `private val binding get() = _binding!!` **Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException**

At some time, can the handler call the runnable before removing it after setting `_binding = null` ??

I don't know why that!

Comment: Are you trying to access the binding variable before onCreateView or after onDestroyView lifecycle methods?

Comment: I access binding inside handler and handler called every 1 millisecond, in such time it my access binding before remove handler? @Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Remove handler callbacks before binding gets null
Correct way

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        handler?.removeCallbacks(this)
        _binding = null
    }
```

Comment: You can update your statement for handler with - handlerRunner?.apply {
            handler.removeCallbacks(this)
        }

Comment: @Muhammed this didn't fix the bug too

Answer (score -1):

You should use DataBinding instead

```
class XBottomSheetFragment () : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

private lateinit var binding: XBottomSheetBinding
private var handlerRunner: Runnable? = null
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_x_bottomsheet, container, false)
        return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    handlerRunner = Runnable {
        binding.tvTimeOffer.text = "text"
   }
   
   handler.postDelayed(handlerRunner!!, 1)
}


override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView() 

    handlerRunner?.apply {
        handler.removeCallbacks(this)
    }
}
```

}

From xml layout, encapsulate your work by layout tag :

```
<layout>
<--- your layout design --->
</layout>
```

P.S. always name your category of class at the end of your classname for easy search and maintenance